# The acid scene in "Suicide Squad"

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

In [Suicide Squad](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1386697/) (2016), there is a scene where

> Harley remembers jumping in what looks like acid containers, followed by Joker. We later see them kissing there, with blue and red paint melted around them in what should be acid, but looks more like milk, and the two of them seem unharmed.

What is the significance of that scene? Was it the final test of Harley's loyalty to Joker and it was never acid in those containers, but only made to look like it was, or am I missing something deeper here?

Comment: Good answers from the guys above. Just to add, it's not paint you are seeing. Harley is wearing blue clothes and Joker is wearing red when they jump into the acid (or is it the other way around... anyway) - this is why her hair has blue and red colour tips, it's the dye from the clothes they were wearing.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It was acid. Just not a melt your face off type acid. It bleached their skin and discolored their hair and clothing. It likely also affected them mentally, but it's debatable if it made them crazy or just proved that they were. It is implied to be the same Ace chemical factory that the Joker is said to have fall in to make him as pale green as we know him.

The significance of the scene is to establish that Joker maybe somehow also actually cared about Harley instead of just toying with her. His face before jumping down seems to show some internal conflict, as of he himself disliked that he felt something for her, which pushed him to save her against his normal desire to kill people.

It's also to establish how Harley became like she did, her look. That she voluntarily became like that,  out of a type of mad love for Mistah J. Unlike her recent comic reboot where he threw her into the acid against her will. The comics make him rapier than the movie.

Then again, as this is a flashback of an "unreliable narrator" like ***batshit*** crazy Harley, we don't know if that's an accurate flashback. For one, she wouldn't have been able to see what Joker does after she fell. Line of Sight issues.

Comment: Given the lengths he went through to break her out of prison, I think its most likely that memory was genuine. I know its not the relationship they had in the cartoons or comics, but that seems to be what they decided to go with for the movie universe.

Comment: I thought it was the electroshock the Joker gave Harley made her (more) crazy, not the vat of bleach. And what made the red and blue color swirls? Dye from their clothes leaching away?

Comment: What confuses me with this explanation, though, is that Harley didn't actually look that much paler than normal at all, certainly not as bad as the Joker, let alone with green hair.

Comment: @Napoleon she goes from normal human pale whitish pink to chalky makeup white pale. It's an opinion though.

Comment: @Napoleon when a good rip comes out I'll show a few comparisons

Answer (score 14):

That scene is homage to her counterpart from [The New 52 reboot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_New_52) of DC comics:

> Following DC's 2011 relaunch of its titles, Harley Quinn's costume and
>   appearance is fully revamped. Harley Quinn has a more revealing
>   costume, altered hair color, and bleached skin. Her hair is half-red
>   and half-black, like the jester cap of her previous incarnation,
>   rather than fully blonde. Consistent with her new origin, her bleached
>   skin is the result of being kicked into a vat of acid by the Joker. 
>   - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harley_Quinn#The_New_52)

[image]

Joker also got his infamous look by similar incident/accident :

> Ace Chemicals is a fictional business organization in the DC Comics
>   universe. It was at Ace Chemicals plant where the Joker (when he was
>   Red Hood) fell into a vat of chemicals, creating his trademark look of
>   green hair, chalk white skin, and red lips. - [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ace_Chemicals)

[image]

That Joker origin story is from [Batman: The Killing Joke](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Killing_Joke) one-shot graphic novel. But Joker serves as an unreliable narrator in it.

> He admits to his own uncertainty, as he has disparate memories of the single event ("Sometimes I remember it one way, sometimes another ... If I'm going to have a past, I prefer it to be multiple choice!") [*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batman:_The_Killing_Joke#Themes_and_analysis)

So that scene was inspired by comics and do seem non explanatory in the film. As per rumors, that scene was supposed to be a bit longer.

Refer [this link](http://comicbook.com/dc/2016/08/06/suicide-squad-rumored-list-of-deleted-scenes-revealed/) for whole list of rumored cut scenes.