# Why did Joker and Harley Quinn jump into the chemical bath (goo container, acid container)?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, suicide-squad

**Question**

Why did Mr. J and Harley jump into the chemical bath in *Suicide Squad*?

---

**Background**

My interpretation is that this was the moment J knew he loved Harley, whereas before it would have been Harley that had to "pass every test" to prove *her* love for J, this scene shows us that now J is being tested by Harley to prove *his* love for her.

> J: Would you die for me?
>
> Harley: Yes
>
> J: That's too easy, would you live for me?
>
> ...
>
> *Harley, then J, dive into a chemical bath*

[**Full Scene on Youtube**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=20apSY_eOUs)

[image]

---

**EDIT**: Possible duplicate. I did try and find it before asking, maybe not hard enough, I think it is because I couldn't find a better search query for "chemical bath", hence the lengthy title of my question to prevent future duplications:

[The acid scene in "Suicide Squad"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/58907/the-acid-scene-in-suicide-squad)

Comment: Related, maybe even duplicate: http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/58907/the-acid-scene-in-suicide-squad

Comment: @cde I've edited the question to make it clear it's a duplicate rather than deleting. Main reason: Your answers to both questions seem pretty authentic and loyal to each of the questions in their own right. Although, I'm pretty sure the question I was trying to articulate was answered in the question you linked... just less easily.

Comment: Joker said _simple_, not _that's too easy_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Harley was pushed, she didn't jump. She felt a Stokholm Syndrome type of "love" after a sociopath like Joker carefully made her fall for him. Also, he forced her to go through electroshock therapy. She was pushed through being *manipulated*. In the source comics, she was literally pushed.

Joker, in this interpretation jumped in against his own judgement, as yes, he starts having some perverted form of love for her. This can be seen by the shaking of his head and the face he makes while he walks away and decides to jump in to save her. He's conflicted. He really had intended to just walk away and let her drown.

The movie was **heavily edited** to lessen the abusive, rapey relationship between Joker and Harley. In the source material, Joker never loved Harley, she was just a convenient tool to him, just like anyone else.

To wit, one major edit in the film was Harley chasing Joker, essentially forcing him to take her with him.

Comment: Did we ever get official confirmation that Joker abuse was edited out of the film? (I believe it was, but I can't recall if we ever got solid evidence for it or just rumours)

Comment: @Ixrec you mean outside of Leto whining about all the edits?

Comment: @lxrec http://www.cinemablend.com/news/1544159/the-problem-with-harley-and-the-jokers-relationship-in-suicide-squad and http://batman-news.com/2016/08/23/uncropped-joker-harley-quinn-abuse/ and http://batman-news.com/2016/08/23/uncropped-joker-harley-quinn-abuse/ there is so much information on scenes shot and dropped, including much of the normal Joker/Harley abuse that the comics show.